# Differentiate expression involving an integral

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

How can I minimize this expression with respect to $c_i$ i.e. differentiate this expression, equate to zero and solve for $c_i$. The expression is $\sqrt{\int_a^b \left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|^2 dx}$. I need to obtain $c_i$ in terms of the other terms.

Comment: First of course minimizing your expression is the same as minimizing its square. Then do some elementary calculus and linear algebra... notice that after squaring your expression and taking a derivative you are left with an equation that is linear in the $c_i$.

Comment: What are they functions $\phi_i(x)$

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by taking the derivative of the expression with respect to $c_i$. Let's call the expression:
   $$
   E(c_i) = \sqrt{\int_a^b \left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|^2 dx}
   \
   $$
   Then, the derivative of $E(c_i)$ with respect to $c_i$ is:

$$
\frac{dE}{dc_i} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_a^b \frac{2}{2} \frac{d}{dc_i}\left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|^2 dx\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \frac{d}{dc_i}\left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|^2
$$

2. Now, you need to compute the derivative of the absolute value term:
   $$
   \
   \frac{d}{dc_i}\left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|^2
   \
   $$
   You can use the chain rule here. Let's denote the absolute value term as $g(x) = \left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|^2$. Then,
   $$
   \
   \frac{d}{dc_i}g(x) = \frac{d}{dg}g(x) \cdot \frac{d}{dc_i}\left(f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x)\right)^2
   \
   $$
   Since the derivative of $g(x)$ with respect to $g$ is simply $2g(x)$, you have:
   $$
   \
   \frac{d}{dc_i}g(x) = 2\left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|\cdot \frac{d}{dc_i}\left(f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x)\right)
   \
   $$
3. Now, calculate the derivative of $f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x)$ with respect to $c_i$:
   $$
   \
   \frac{d}{dc_i}\left(f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x)\right) = -\phi_i(x)
   \
   $$
4. Plug the result from step 3 into step 2:
   $$
   \
   \frac{d}{dc_i}g(x) = -2\left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|\cdot \phi_i(x)
   \
   $$
5. Now, plug the result from step 4 into step 1:
   $$
   \
   \frac{dE}{dc_i} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_a^b \frac{2}{2} \left(-2\left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|\cdot \phi_i(x)\right) dx\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
   \
   $$
6. Simplify and solve for $c_i$:
   $$
   \
   \frac{dE}{dc_i} = -\frac{\left(\int_a^b \left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|\cdot \phi_i(x) dx\right)}{E(c_i)}
   \
   $$
7. Set $\frac{dE}{dc_i}$ equal to zero and solve for $c_i$:
   $$
   \
   0 = \int_a^b \left| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \phi_i(x) \right|\cdot \phi_i(x) dx
   \
   $$
8. Solving the equation can be a good challenge.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got to this level. The challenge is to move beyond this because $\phi_i (x)$ is a piecewise function $\begin{cases} \frac{x-x_{i-1}}{x_i - x_{i-1}}; x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\\\frac{x_{i+1}-x}{x_{i+1}-x_i}; x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}] \end{cases}$